# Seperate Annotation default text

Tags: arcgis-desktop, annotation

Is there any way for the default text of each annotation subtype to be different? I tried modifying my TextString default value through ArcCatalog but that does not seem to produce any results.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to revise it with relevant details from the responses that you have made in comments to requests for clarifications, please?

Answer (score 1):

How is the annotation stored?  If it's within a geodatabase, not within the map then this should work:

Start an edit session with your annotation layer added to ArcMap. Select all annotations --> right click on a given annotation and click "attributes" from here you should have a list of all your selected annotations. 
From here, change the font/size/colour what have you and save your edits and refresh the page. This should change the annotation.

Also see [About changing and editing annotations.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m70000000w000000) and [changing attributes of annotation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m70000000w000000)

You can also do this directly from the attribute table and use the field calculator.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the annotation is stored within the geodatabase. I have looked up that documentation but it's not what I'm looking for. I want a label to displayed for each annotation depending on which subtype in the feature template I've clicked on, I've managed to change the default 'Text' string on a new feature class but I have yet to make it behave based on which subtype I've chosen from the Create Features window.

Comment: I think what you mean is that you want the annotation to be based on the symbology of a specific feature class? Is that correct?

Comment: Yep, I just want the attribute to be populated without any typing.

Comment: You may want to look into Maplex labelling engine to define your SQL queries defined by the attribute in the symbology and sub classes there. From there, convert to annotation.